# Is there h2o support for Mac M1?

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to run h2o in following the installation guide from [here](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#:%7E:text=the%20H2O%20website.-,install%20in%20python,-Run%20the%20following). I expect a successful initialization with my code but instead get an error.

I am using `Python 3.10.8` on Mac M1 macOS Monterey. Is it possible that there is no M1 support yet?

**Code**

```py
import h2o
h2o.init()
h2o.demo("glm")
```

**Error**

`CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/java', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: do you have Java installed?

Comment: Google "install Java on Mac M1"

Comment: Indeed getting Java helped. I was just to hasty because I didn't expected this to be a requirement since its not listed as a requirement in the documentation (okay there is a link to a requirement file but this link is dead). @blankettripod

Comment: @MaxHager Java is listed as a requirement in the H2O user guide: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html#requirements
Can you point me to the dead link you're talking about?

Comment: The link on [this](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#:~:text=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fh2oai%2Fh2o-3%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fh2o-py%2Fconda%2Fh2o%2Fmeta.yaml.) site under "Install in Python" point 1. @ErinLeDell

Comment: Thanks @MaxHager! I will get that link updated.